# Find function does not work

Tags: vb.net, function

I keep having problems with the find function.

There are two sheets involved. Basically i want to fill in the main sheet that have dates from Jan 2011 to December 2012. I tried to match these dates in the raw data sheet named export so that i can retrieve the next value to these dates.

However, it seems that the value for `cellFound` cannot be found. It keeps giving me application-defined or object-defined error. Can you help me with this?

**My code:**

```
Sub Rectangle2_Click()

Dim searchDate As Long, cellFound As Range, searchRange As Range
Dim i As Integer

Set searchRange = Worksheets("Export").Range("G77:G91")

For i = 2 To 25

searchDate = Worksheets("Main").Cells(2, i)

Set cellFound = searchRange.Find(What:=searchDate, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

Worksheets("Main").Cells(4, i) = cellFound

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the possibility of finding returning no results:

```
If cellFound Is Nothing Then
'handle error
    Debug.Print ("error")
Else
    Worksheets(2).Cells(4, i) = cellFound
End If
```

Exactly WHY there is no result I cannot guess - please give us some sample data.

Comment: erm..how to attach the file here?

Comment: It is not possibly I think - upload the file somewehre and post the link

Comment: http://fs06u.sendspace.com/upload?SPEED_LIMIT=0&MAX_FILE_SIZE=314572800&UPLOAD_IDENTIFIER=736601377.1363002380.73842447.17.0&DESTINATION_DIR=1